# On Ajax call MVC.Grid Updated but css not applied :( Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, grid

All things working fine 1st time data render fine but when click on any page number then with Ajax call data fetch successfully all headers and footer css remain the same but css of table rows de-attached not included please if you have any suggestion tell me.

Advance Thanks

Before ajax call this is the rendered html in browser.

```
<html lang="en" class=" js no-flexbox flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index - Anchor Bay Insurance Managers, Inc.</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/TwoColumnForm.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/spin.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/ladda.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/URI.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/gridmvc-ext.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">window.EBCallBackMessageReceived_ec65_a99d_1166_10f1_472b_e904_7a5b_da73 = function (data) {window.postMessage({name: 'EBCallBackMessageReceived', msg: data, id:'ec65_a99d_1166_10f1_472b_e904_7a5b_da73'}, '*')};if (window.addEventListener) { 
  var callback_func = function(evt) { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof evt.target && "A" == evt.target.nodeName) { 
      var url = evt.target.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_ec65_a99d_1166_10f1_472b_e904_7a5b_da73(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = window.addEventListener('click', callback_func, true); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = window.addEventListener('contextmenu', callback_func, true); 
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  var callback_func = function () { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof event.srcElement &&'A' == event.srcElement.tagName) { 
      var url = event.srcElement.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_ec65_a99d_1166_10f1_472b_e904_7a5b_da73(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = document.attachEvent('onclick', callback_func); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', callback_func); 
} 


</script><script type="text/javascript">window.EBCallBackMessageReceived_ccb0_9b98_55aa_c6cc_ff2e_a9db_6021_c2dd = function (data) {window.postMessage({name: 'EBCallBackMessageReceived', msg: data, id:'ccb0_9b98_55aa_c6cc_ff2e_a9db_6021_c2dd'}, '*')};if (window.addEventListener) { 
  var callback_func = function(evt) { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof evt.target && "A" == evt.target.nodeName) { 
      var url = evt.target.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_ccb0_9b98_55aa_c6cc_ff2e_a9db_6021_c2dd(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = window.addEventListener('click', callback_func, true); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = window.addEventListener('contextmenu', callback_func, true); 
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  var callback_func = function () { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof event.srcElement &&'A' == event.srcElement.tagName) { 
      var url = event.srcElement.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_ccb0_9b98_55aa_c6cc_ff2e_a9db_6021_c2dd(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = document.attachEvent('onclick', callback_func); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', callback_func); 
} 


</script></head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Restaurant Bar &amp; Tavern Program</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">

        Hello, <a class="username" href="/Agent/AgentProfile/33" title="Manage">azhar63</a>!
<form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="lZ1mXfXGZsdpR9aYMjceHEQ8KEYvb7P8zyxe9e-Yoj2cmFF761uvsOxtLEdOxm-_NG6lk9nBihRrNUBzLGMZ0w5lYTePwYNqWfEmDzCsCew1">            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
</form>    

                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="body">



                     <header>
                        <div class="content-wrapper">
                            <div class="float-left">
                                    <ul id="menu">
                                                <li><a href="/">Agency</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Agent">Agent</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Applicant/Quote">Quote</a></li>

                                                        <li><a href="/MetaData">Email Templates</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">




<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



            <ul id="menu">
                  <li><a href="/Agent/Create">Create Agent</a></li>
            </ul>



<h2>Agents</h2>
<div class="boxDiv" style="width:100%">



<div style="width:100%">
            <div class="grid-mvc" data-lang="en" data-gridname="metaData" data-selectable="true" data-multiplefilters="false">
        <div class="grid-wrap">
            <table class="table table-striped grid-table">

                <thead>
                        <tr>
<th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=FirstName&amp;grid-dir=0">First Name</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=LastName&amp;grid-dir=0">Last Name</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentUserInfo.UserName&amp;grid-dir=0">UserName</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentOfAgency.Name&amp;grid-dir=0">Agency</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentUserInfo.Email&amp;grid-dir=0">Email</a></div></th><th class="grid-header" style="width:15%;"><div class="grid-header-title"><span></span></div></th>    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr class="grid-row ">
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="FirstName">Muhammad Atif</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="LastName">Aziz</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentUserInfo.UserName">atif17</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentOfAgency.Name">Test</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentUserInfo.Email">atif.aziz@nxb.com.pk</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="">    <div class="grid-action-links">
        <a href="/Agent/Details/57" title="Detail View"><i></i></a>
            <a href="/Agent/Details/57#update" title="Update"><i></i></a>
            <span class="light1">|</span>
            <a class="delete" href="/Agent/Delete/57" title="Delete"><i></i></a>
    </div>
</td>    </tr>
    <tr class="grid-row ">
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="FirstName">Sanan</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="LastName">Chatha</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentUserInfo.UserName">sanan63</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentOfAgency.Name">Test</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="AgentUserInfo.Email">azhar.abim@nxvt.com</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="">    <div class="grid-action-links">
        <a href="/Agent/Details/56" title="Detail View"><i></i></a>
            <a href="/Agent/Details/56#update" title="Update"><i></i></a>
            <span class="light1">|</span>
            <a class="delete" href="/Agent/Delete/56" title="Delete"><i></i></a>
    </div>
</td>    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
                <div class="grid-footer">

<div class="grid-footer">
    <div class="grid-pager">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#" class="grid-prev-page" title="Previous Page" style="display: none"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a class="grid-page-link" data-page="1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="grid-page-link" data-page="2">2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" title="Next Page" class="grid-next-page"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).on("change",function () {
    //    $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").refreshFullGrid();
    //});
    //$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

    //      $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //});
</script>

</div>

        <script src="/Scripts/gridmvcajax.custom.js"></script>



        <script src="/Content/Scripts/Global.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            pageGrids.metaData.ajaxify(
            {
                getPagedData: "/Agent/Grid",
                getData: "/Agent/Index"
            });
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();
        });
    </script>


            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p style="padding-top:10px;">© 2014 - Anchor Bay Insurance Managers, Inc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

After Ajax call this is the rendered html in browser.

```
<html lang="en" class=" js no-flexbox flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index - Anchor Bay Insurance Managers, Inc.</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/TwoColumnForm.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/spin.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/ladda.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/URI.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/gridmvc-ext.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">window.EBCallBackMessageReceived_9c96_3370_b919_1fd0_f16c_76ca_4bda_54b9 = function (data) {window.postMessage({name: 'EBCallBackMessageReceived', msg: data, id:'9c96_3370_b919_1fd0_f16c_76ca_4bda_54b9'}, '*')};if (window.addEventListener) { 
  var callback_func = function(evt) { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof evt.target && "A" == evt.target.nodeName) { 
      var url = evt.target.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_9c96_3370_b919_1fd0_f16c_76ca_4bda_54b9(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = window.addEventListener('click', callback_func, true); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = window.addEventListener('contextmenu', callback_func, true); 
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  var callback_func = function () { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof event.srcElement &&'A' == event.srcElement.tagName) { 
      var url = event.srcElement.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_9c96_3370_b919_1fd0_f16c_76ca_4bda_54b9(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = document.attachEvent('onclick', callback_func); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', callback_func); 
} 


</script><script type="text/javascript">window.EBCallBackMessageReceived_7e3f_667e_eaf1_f8e4_cbe5_0a2a_b8c4_6119 = function (data) {window.postMessage({name: 'EBCallBackMessageReceived', msg: data, id:'7e3f_667e_eaf1_f8e4_cbe5_0a2a_b8c4_6119'}, '*')};if (window.addEventListener) { 
  var callback_func = function(evt) { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof evt.target && "A" == evt.target.nodeName) { 
      var url = evt.target.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_7e3f_667e_eaf1_f8e4_cbe5_0a2a_b8c4_6119(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = window.addEventListener('click', callback_func, true); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = window.addEventListener('contextmenu', callback_func, true); 
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  var callback_func = function () { 
    if ('undefined' != typeof event.srcElement &&'A' == event.srcElement.tagName) { 
      var url = event.srcElement.href; 
      EBCallBackMessageReceived_7e3f_667e_eaf1_f8e4_cbe5_0a2a_b8c4_6119(url); 
    } 
    return true; 
  }; 
  var cb_add_listener_result_click = document.attachEvent('onclick', callback_func); 
  var cb_add_listener_result_contextmenu = document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', callback_func); 
} 


</script></head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Restaurant Bar &amp; Tavern Program</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">

        Hello, <a class="username" href="/Agent/AgentProfile/33" title="Manage">azhar63</a>!
<form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="wvvSbtslTZV3nqpwsX2eWoeHa91OwSxF0ne60C6QLvWeWEKVKZhhembtcbPeVLMKlVBKGA7bcK4oAnIIoK5yhG_DrAJRASQZbV_uyqeJLqQ1">            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
</form>    

                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="body">



                     <header>
                        <div class="content-wrapper">
                            <div class="float-left">
                                    <ul id="menu">
                                                <li><a href="/">Agency</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Agent">Agent</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/Applicant/Quote">Quote</a></li>

                                                        <li><a href="/MetaData">Email Templates</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">




<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



            <ul id="menu">
                  <li><a href="/Agent/Create">Create Agent</a></li>
            </ul>



<h2>Agents</h2>
<div class="boxDiv" style="width:100%">



<div style="width:100%">
            <div class="grid-mvc" data-lang="en" data-gridname="metaData" data-selectable="true" data-multiplefilters="false">
        <div class="grid-wrap">
            <table class="table table-striped grid-table">

                <thead>
                        <tr>
<th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=FirstName&amp;grid-dir=0">First Name</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=LastName&amp;grid-dir=0">Last Name</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentUserInfo.UserName&amp;grid-dir=0">UserName</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentOfAgency.Name&amp;grid-dir=0">Agency</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=AgentUserInfo.Email&amp;grid-dir=0">Email</a></div></th><th class="grid-header" style="width:15%;"><div class="grid-header-title"><span></span></div></th>    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

<div style="width:100%">

AslamNadeemaslam17Testazhar.ynn@nxvt.com    <div class="grid-action-links">
        <a href="/Agent/Details/55" title="Detail View"><i></i></a>
            <a href="/Agent/Details/55#update" title="Update"><i></i></a>
            <span class="light1">|</span>
            <a class="delete" href="/Agent/Delete/55" title="Delete"><i></i></a>
    </div>


Malik AzharAwanazhar63Testazhar.rafique@nxb.com.pk    <div class="grid-action-links">
        <a href="/Agent/Details/33" title="Detail View"><i></i></a>
            <a href="/Agent/Details/33#update" title="Update"><i></i></a>
            <span class="light1">|</span>
            <a class="delete" href="/Agent/Delete/33" title="Delete"><i></i></a>
    </div>


    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).on("change",function () {
    //    $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").refreshFullGrid();
    //});
    //$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

    //      $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //});
</script></tbody>
            </table>
                <div class="grid-footer">

<div class="grid-footer">
    <div class="grid-pager">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#" class="grid-prev-page" title="Previous Page" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span></a></li>
                <li class=""><a class="grid-page-link" data-page="1" href="">1</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="" class="grid-page-link" data-page="2">2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" title="Next Page" class="grid-next-page" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).on("change",function () {
    //    $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //    //$(".grid-mvc").refreshFullGrid();
    //});
    //$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

    //      $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc().refreshFullGrid();
    //});
</script>

</div>

        <script src="/Scripts/gridmvcajax.custom.js"></script>



        <script src="/Content/Scripts/Global.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            pageGrids.metaData.ajaxify(
            {
                getPagedData: "/Agent/Grid",
                getData: "/Agent/Index"
            });
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $(".grid-mvc").gridmvc();
        });
    </script>


            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p style="padding-top:10px;">© 2014 - Anchor Bay Insurance Managers, Inc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is your css loaded? is it included in the layout page, or is there some logic that applies the css at runtime?

Comment: it is not loaded in layout page it is included in main page from which partial view of grid is rendered

Comment: @tintyethan can you please help me?

Comment: When you make your ajax call, what is returned? Is it a partial view? If so, try including the relevant css in the partial view - just to test.

Comment: yes it is partial view i did it too but not succeeded :(

Comment: can you post the output html - the html rendered in the browser - or give me a link to the page if its public

Comment: @tintyethan thanks for your response i updated my question please take a look. May be it gives any clue ...

Comment: @tintyethan........?

Comment: it looks like your table tags are getting stripped out - I had the same problem and ended up converting my table tags to divs - you can define the widths of the column divs for the header, footer, and table cells (which will now all be divs), to get everything to line up properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table tags are getting stripped out and converted to divs durring the ajax call - I had the same problem and ended up converting my table tags to divs - you can define the widths of the column divs for the header, footer, and table cells (which will now all be divs), to get everything to line up properly.